can a trivia app be subject to betting / gambling laws?
I want to create a 2-player trivia game website where 2 players put $3 and the winner gets something like $5.70. The exact numbers don't matter. Can this be subject to gambling laws? Is it gambling? I believe not because your performance (winnings) doesn't depend on chance but on knowledge / skill. But legal issues are so tricky.
I understand it depends on a country and even a state in the US. I'd like to get feedback on all countries about which you know.
Does someone have any first-hand experience with such issues?

My company operates an online bridge (card game) service, and we used to have a similar feature. While we considered it a skill game, a number of countries consider any card game with money stakes to be gambling, so we had to block it in those countries. I don't have the list of countries.

Thank you, Barmar

Consider all the countries which regulate sports betting. One could try to argue that it is a game of skill, judging the performance of the two skills.

Your customers are still "gambling" on getting the right set of questions (not known before, to them it will be a random draw).
They are also "gambling" on being better than their competition, which is not perfectly known to them.

There are many more problems in your business plan:

You are taking money and paying it out. In many jurisdictions, there would be money laundering concerns. Ever since the crackdown on terror financing, some of these laws have teeth. You need to know your customers.

Not exactly a legal issue:

If you want to distribute your app on one of the big appstores, they will want a percentage of any "in-app purchases." That cuts significantly into your potential payouts.
The mechanics of getting paid such small amounts will also cut into your profit margin.


Thank you for your reply! I'm not sure that it is exactly "You are taking money and paying it out". Each player pays, say, $3 and the winner takes the funds except the rake which is 30 cents (to cover development fees, servers, etc). So, the winner should win to gain $5.70. Any idea where I can get a list of countries regulating sports betting?

@FadaiMammadov I got a map with gambling laws worldwide within 20 seconds of googling: https://slotegrator.pro/gambling-regulations-map/ - but for some african and latin american states, any betting online is either regulated or illegal in most countries.

thank you, @Trish!

@FadaiMammadov, players A and B pay $3.00 each. Your payment provider will take a large chunk of that, some covers the server, some goes to taxes, and whatever is left goes back to player A . You are not just facilitating a payment between B and A, you are paying A.

@Trish Many countries don't consider it to be gambling if you're betting on your own skill. We used to operate a head-to-head bridge game where you win your opponent's stake (minus our rake), and we only had to block it in a handful of countries.

@Barmar Let me make it clearer for you: some countries ban all betting. Some countries ban only games of luck. Others ban anything that is not a game of skill.  Some ban any internet gambling but not in person or vice versa. Others again are vastly more complex. while your game might be ok, what matters is the regulation in any country the game is availeable.

@Trish I understand that. And when we ran this game, I believe our management tried to find out which countries it was legal in. I don't have the list now. But I think it was legal in most countries.

@Barmar that's why I just linked to a general page that gives a general hint "here you need to follow regulations, here gambling is banned" - takign that as a start for the research and then asking a lawyer that is paid would be the proper path. My point is mostly: "Betting is regulated in many countries, familiarize yourself with the laws there and if the game is legal or not." Game of Skill is not generally an acceptable term worldwide.
